# When do primes lift uniquely (provided they lift at all)?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Given a ring $R$, a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $R$, and an extension ring $S$ (the algebra map $R\to S$ is injective), are there any nontrivial sufficient conditions for the induced map $Spec(S) \to Spec(R)$ to be injective as a map of topological spaces (completely disregarding any of our sheaf structure)?  That is, every prime that lifts lifts to a unique prime?  If this problem is intractable as-is, I can add more conditions, so please don't add answers unless they are actual answers.

Comment: If R--->S is strict epimorhism which is surjective map.Then Spec(S)-->Spec(R) is a closed immersion(as closed subvariety) 

Comment: A strict epimorphism of rings is surjective, no?

Comment: Is "strict epimorphism" synonymous with "surjection"? If not, could somebody define the former for me?

Comment: Haha, I think it's another incarnation of radiciel but flipped around. 

Comment: It seems to me that there is a disconnect between the title and the body of the question.  "When do primes lift uniquely?" seems to be asking "When is it the case that for every prime ideal p of R, there is exactly one prime ideal of S lying over p?" which is a wordier way of asking when the map on spectra is bijective.  This is why some people are responsing with radiciel/purely inseparable extensions.  On the other hand, in the body it seems to simply be asking for the map on spectra to be injective, which e.g. as VA points out occurs much more commonly... 

Comment: ...e.g. for any localization map, when Spec S has a single point, etc.  Please clarify.

Comment: I wanted to put in parentheses in the title "(If it lifts at all)", but I forgot to do it after writing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than listing various non-trivial sufficient conditions, let me give you a reference. Search EGA for the word "radiciel" (or start reading at Definition 3.5.4 of EGA I). A morphism of schemes $X\to Y$ is said to be *radiciel* (or *universally injective*) if for every field $K$, the induced map on $K$-points $X(K)\to Y(K)$ is injective. This generalizes the notion of a purely inseparable field extension.

Comment: Are these as functors of points?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: Oh no, it was clear.  Is there a nice translation of this into an algebraic condition?  

Comment: Yes.  Look in EGA or in the stacks project.

Comment: Well, one obviously equivalent algebraic condition is that the tensor product (over R) of S (the extension) with any residue field of R is a purely inseparable extension of that residue field.

Comment: Section 20.11 of the stacks project (Radicial morphisms) and Proposition 3.5.8 of EGA I suggest the same algebraic condition I proposed, so I suspect you can't say anything better.

Comment: Is that really an answer to this question? ("completely disregarding the sheaf structure"). Take any field extension $S/R$. Then $Spec(S)\to Spec(R)$ is injective but there is nothing "radiciel" about this. 

Comment: @VA: you're absolutely right. Universally injective is certainly a much stronger condition than injective. Somehow I latched on to universal injectivity and forgot to look back at the question.

Comment: Can that tensor product fail to be a field?  Or am I just computing wrong?

Comment: @Harry: sure it can. For example, take S=R⊕R. If S is finite over R (I think I caught a glimpse of a comment that S is integral over R in your situation), then the tensor product will be a finite sum of fields.

Comment: Anton, I'm really sorry, but after unraveling definitions, this is literally an equivalent condition to the question.  Would you be upset if I pulled the "accepted answer" off of your answer?

Comment: @Harry: of course not; if this didn't answer your question, it shouldn't be the accepted answer. But do take note of VA's comment. Radiciel is much stronger than what you asked for in your question, so if you've found that it's equivalent to what you're trying to get, you should edit your question.

Comment: It turns out that in the question that I really wanted to ask but couldn't because it was a homework question, I get the radiciel for free from injectivity because the extension is integral.  Either way, I actually sat down and wrote out the proof, and it has absolutely nothing to do with any of these criteria.  It comes down to the fact that we just end up with a ring where everything is nilpotent or a unit.  I should have computed before posting this question.  

Comment: So your answer was good enough!  The original hidden question that motivated this question was: "Let $R$ be a subring of a ring $S$ such that $S=R[u]$, where $u^m$ and $u^n$ are in $R$ and $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.  Show that the induced map $Spec(S)\to Spec(R)$ is bijective."  Surjectivity is immediate by integrality.  Fix a prime p in R.  If u^m or u^n is not in p, then it follows by Bezout's lemma for integers that $R_{u^m}=S_u$, so by corollary 5.8 of Atiyah-MacDonald, the primes away from u^m or u^n lift uniquely.  For primes containing u^m or u^n, it follows by a direct check.

Comment: I pretty much wasted 4-5 hours trying to avoid a direct check.  I feel like a total idiot.

Answer (score 4):

If $S/R$ is purely inseparable then the primes will lift uniquely.

Comment: Could you give a reference? This looks like the condition I needed. Well, also, what do you mean by S/R is purely inseparable? Isn't that a condition on field extensions?